# Check if value is between two numbers in Java

Tags: java

I am in a programming class and we are making a simple program. In this program the user will put in five assignments, the points they got on that assignment and the total points available. I have all of the basic things except for a grading scale. I am trying to make it so when their percent is between 92 and 100 percent it will say you have an A in this class. This is what I have so far:

```
if ( pC >= 92, pC <= 100 ) {
    System.out.print("\n You have an B");
}
```

So far that has not worked and I am having a lot of trouble.

Comment: Javascript or Java? Because you have Java syntax.

Comment: Java is to Javascript what elect is to electronic.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if ( pC >= 92 && pC <= 100 ) {`

Comment: First of all you should look up boolean statements because they don't have commas. Second, that looks like the grade range for an A and you having it as a B is just bothering me =]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do is check if a number is >= 92 AND <= 100. That isn't done with a comma, like you have:

```
if ( pC >= 92, pC <= 100 ) {
    System.out.print("\n You have an B");
}
```

Rather, the AND operator is `&&` (and you said you want this range to be an A, rather than a B), which means your code would look like this:

```
if ( pC >= 92 && pC <= 100 ) {
    System.out.print("\n You have an A");
}
```

Comment: I have only been in this class for about a week. I thought it was JavaScript i guess I know better now. Thank you for the answer, I will have to try it when I get back. And that B was supposed to be an A.  I got the comma from another question on here and they said it would work. But again thank you very much.

Comment: There may be some other programming language which uses commas to represent an AND operator - but yeah, in Java it's `&&`. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is this:

If the point is between 92% and 100%:

```
if ( pC >= 92 && pC <= 100 ) {
    System.out.print("\n You have an A");
}
```

If the point is out that range:

```
if ( pC < 92 ) {
    System.out.print("\n You have an B");
}
```

Or, to the complete statement, you will want to make:

```
if ( pC >= 92 && pC <= 100 ) {
  System.out.print("\n You have an A");
}
else if ( pC < 92 ){
  System.out.print("\n You have an B");
}
else {
  System.out.print("\n You have a point out of the curve");
}
```